# Center image element in parent div

Tags: html, css, image

How I can set center an image element inside a parent div? I would like to do this so that the middle of the image is always in the center of his parent. Also I want the image to always have 100% height (note: I don't want to stretch the image width).

See here for an example: http://jsfiddle.net/Ex5ax/5/

```
<div class="box">
  <img src='featured.jpg' />
</div>
```

CSS:

```
.box { height: 100%; width: 450px; border: 2px solid red; background: green; overflow: hidden; }
.box img { height: 100%; width: auto; text-align: center; }
```

Comment: I really don't understand. You say don't want to stretch the width, but the image-size is 640px and the width of parent is 450px. You would at least have to reduce the image-width (stretch) to 450px?

Answer (score 12):

Add `text-align: center;` CSS declaration to the parent `.box` instead of the children `.box img`.

```
.box {
    height: 100%;
    width: 450px;
    border: 2px solid red;
    background: green;
    overflow: hidden;
    text-align: center;  /* align center all inline elements */
}
```

Here is the **[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/qolami/Ex5ax/10/)**.

### Update

It seems there's also a `5px` gap under the image, It belongs to the line height reserved characters. To remove that from inline elements like `<img>` you can use `vertical-align: bottom`:

```
.box img {
    height: 100%;
    width: auto;
    vertical-align: bottom; /* <-- fix the vertical gap */
}
```

**[JSFiddle Demo #2](http://jsfiddle.net/qolami/Ex5ax/25/)**

Comment: While this does work in the example given, I don't feel that this is a good general answer to the question, because it has the side-effect of centering all text and all images within the parent div.   A better solution would be to style only the element that one specifically wants to center, without affecting the entire contents of the parent.    `display:block; margin:auto` on the img is one solution which will center only the image and not affect the larger scope of the parent

Answer (score 5):

You'll need to move the `text-align: center;` from the CSS for the image to the CSS for its parent div, so your CSS looks like this:

```
.box {
    height: 100%;
    width: 450px;
    border: 2px solid red;
    background: green;
    overflow: hidden; 
    text-align:center
}

.box img {
    height: 100%;
    width: auto;
}
```

And that's it!

Comment: I don't know what I do wrong, but the image will not centered in the div: http://jsfiddle.net/Ex5ax/17/

Answer (score 2):

In case anyone lands up here looking for a solution, here's one using `display: flex`.

```
.box {
   display:flex;
   justify-content: center;
   align-items: center;
   background: green;
   border: 2px solid red;
   height: 100%;
   width: 450px;
   overflow: hidden;   
}
.box img {
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
}
```

Comment: this was the only solution that worked for me

Answer (score 0):

Try giving the image margin property as `margin:0 auto`, if your parent div has width so the image will be centered as per parent

Comment: In this case, the correct approach is to give a text-align: center; property on the parent div

Answer (score 0):

If you express width in percent, you can center using margins:

```
.box img {
    width: 80%;
    margin-left: 10%;
    margin-right: 10%;
}
```

Answer (score -1):

I would add this to .box img.

```
.box img { margin-left: -25%; margin-top: -25%; }
```

You would probably need to ajust these per image, or maybe not due to the dimensions.

Comment: Negative margins is OK to use in certain cases, but absolutely no in this one because there are better alternatives.