# Want text to wrap inside div

Tags: html, word-wrap, css

In my code below, I have 3 images with a caption below some images. I don't want the width of the text to exceed the width of the image. NOTE: the width of the images can vary. It is not a fixed width. If the text exceeds the width of the image, the text needs to wrap. Another problem I have in the code below is that the second and third images show some padding at the bottom of the image. The border around this image should have no padding.

http://jsfiddle.net/AndroidDev/Asu7V/15/

```
<div style="width:300px; overflow-x: auto;white-space: nowrap;">
    <div style="vertical-align:top">
        <div class="x">
            <img src="http://25.media.tumblr.com/avatar_dae559818d30_128.png" />
            <div style="white-space:wrap">Grumpy Cat is a famous cat</div>
        </div>
        <div class="x">
            <img src="http://scottsdalepethotel.com/wp-content/uploads/et_temp/cat-648150_128x128.jpg" />
            <img src="http://playgo.ro/wp-content/themes/play3.0/play.png" style="position:absolute; left:0; top:0" />
        </div>
        <div class="x">
            <img src="http://blog.sureflap.com/wp-content/uploads/2011/11/Maru.jpg" />
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you are not assigning any `width` to your `div` element so assign it, and than use `white-space: normal;`

```
<div style="white-space: normal; width: 130px;">Grumpy Cat is a famous cat</div>
```

[**Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/Asu7V/17/)

Again, would like to warn you that avoid using inline styles..

Also, when you fix the wrapper `div` which contains only image, it is better to use `max-width` and `max-height` for your `img` so it will ensure that it won't `overflow`.

Also, last but not the least, consider using a `p` element instead of `div` which will give some semantic meaning to your text.

---

You were using `white-space: wrap;` where `wrap` is not a valid value for `white-space` property, so you will need `normal`

---

As you commented, you want to get rid of white space on either side, so for that, fix the wrapper element by assigning some fixed `width` to the wrapper element, and for the white space below the image issue, can be fixed by either using `font-size: 0;` on the wrapper element and than assigning some `font-size` to the text, or the better way to go is to use `display: block;` for your `img` element.

Comment: From the question: "NOTE: the width of the images can vary. It is not a fixed width."

Comment: That's pretty close but I notice that there is a small amount of padding on the right side of the image with your code. Any way to remove that? And how can I remove the padding from the other images?

Comment: @AndroidDev I've fixed the wrapper element, just assign some fixed height and use `font-size: 0;` http://jsfiddle.net/Asu7V/19/ and than assign some size to the text wrapper `div`

Comment: @AndroidDev Or you can use `display: block;` for your images http://jsfiddle.net/Asu7V/21/

Comment: I've never seen this before: ".x > div" What does the greater sign mean?

Comment: @AndroidDev that means select element which is direct child to parent, will throw you an example, and for your thing, use `display: block;` for `img` tag, that's better

Comment: @AndroidDev Also check [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/18429014/1725764) to figure out the reason of 5px gap at the bottom of the images.

Comment: @AndroidDev http://jsfiddle.net/tj3dE/ if you won't use that, than see what it selects http://jsfiddle.net/tj3dE/1/

Answer (score 0):

Width is missing from you css, here is a demo :  [**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/Asu7V/20/)

**HTML**

```
<div style=""><span class="text">Grumpy Cat is a famous cat</span>
```

**CSS**

```
 .text {
        vertical-align:top;
        display:inline-block;
        white-space:normal;
        word-wrap: break-word;
        width:70%;
        max-width:70%;
    }
    .x {
        border:1px solid #000000;
        display:inline-block;
        white-space:nowrap;
        position:relative;
        width:42%;
        vertical-align: top;
    }
```

Comment: I made a slight adjustment to your code but the right border is inset by a few pixels. Otherwise, your solution is better than Mr. Aliens because it doesn't rely on a fixed width. Any way to fix the right border? http://jsfiddle.net/AndroidDev/Asu7V/23/

Comment: @AndroidDev : if its 2-3px and permissible by you, then `overflow:hidden` is a solution as its not making much of a difference in image => http://jsfiddle.net/Asu7V/24/ **OR** if you want precision with the width, this is another way(but i wont prefer it) => http://jsfiddle.net/Asu7V/25/......my suggestion, go with `overflow` if you can ignore some pixels!!

Answer (score 0):

An easy way to do it would be wrap your image and the text in one div so that when your image size increases it will also provide the same area for text to flow and will not go beyond the image as well.