# CSS Tag's will not show in center of page

Tags: css, drupal, center

I'm a css newbie and I am using DRUPAL (CMS) to design my site. I have been able to center a image by using this tag:

```
#block-imageblock-4{
    width:25.5%;
    height:10%;
    text-align:center;
    margin-top:1%;
    margin-bottom:1%;
    margin-left:37%;
    margin-right:36.5%;
}
```

So if the screen resolution is 1366px768px(max #page) or larger  #block-imageblock-4 stays in the center of the page.

WELL on another page I have two images with two tags. I used this CSS to place them side by side.

```
#block-imageblock-17,#block-rotating-banner-1{
    display:block;
    width:auto;
    margin-left:2%;

}
```

There respective tags:

```
#block-imageblock-17{
    width:15%;
    float:left;
    margin-top:1%;
    margin-left:3%;
    margin-right:1.5%;
    margin-bottom:5%;
}

#block-rotating-banner-1 {
    margin-right:-30%;
    margin-top:1%;
    margin-bottom:10%;
    float:left;
    background-repeat:no-repeat;
    width:26%;
    height:180px;
    max-width:100%;
    min-height:100%;
    background-image:url("/sites/default/files/imgs/ArtistFrame.png");
}
```

**However if the screen resolution is larger than 1366px by 768px then the images are not centered.** and thats my problem.

I have noticed that if I take out all float and margins out of both tags and put both elements like this:

```
#block-imageblock-17,#block-rotating-banner-1 {
    display:block;
    width:auto;
    text-align:center;
    margin-top:1%;
    margin-bottom:1%;
    margin-left:37%;
    margin-right:36.5%;
}
```

the two images ARE CENTERED, BUT NOT next to each other.

Any suggestions to get both images side by side and in the center of the page like tag  `#block-imageblock-4` ?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Center image element in parent div](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18428997/center-image-element-in-parent-div)

Comment: Why did you edit tag? I am creating this site with Drupal. There for the drupal tag should be applied

Comment: This is a CSS issue definitely, it has nothing to do with any content management system such as drupal.

Answer (score 0):

Try wrapping the images in a `<div>` tag and centering the div using `margin: 0 auto;` . 
Something like this

CSS

```
 .centerDiv { margin: 0 auto;}
```

HTML

```
<div class="centerDiv">
<img src="urlhere" />
...
</div>
```

Comment: .centerDiv needs to have its width explicitly defined

Comment: If you have access to the site template, you can modify the html block and add the div html to surround the block. (Assuming you are doing it in a block). If I remember correctly, it should be the `.tpl.php` files but it has been a while. Other than that, you would just need to update the CSS with the correct centering markup and not the % based markup you are currently using.

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
img {
   height: 250px;
   left: 50%;
   margin-top: -125px;
   margin-left: -125px;
   position: absolute;
   top: 50%;
   width: 250px;   
}
```

and more here:

http://www.paulund.co.uk/absolute-center-images-with-css

Answer (score 0):

```
div
{
    margin: 0 auto;
    width: 100px;
}
img
{
    width: 100px;
}
```

the width of an element with "margin: 0 auto;" needs to have its width EXPLICITLY defined. See [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/37bkH/)