# parent div with img child with width: 100%, height: auto, always leaves 2px height gap

Tags: css

I'm trying to have a stack of divs with fullscreen image as its child, but the parent div height doesn't match the img height.

The CSS is not too complicated

```
  .content {
    overflow: hidden;
    position: relative;

    min-width: 1024px

  }

  .content img {
    width: 100%;
    height: auto;
  }
```

Here's the JSBin http://jsbin.com/baqexonu/1/ , you'll notice a 2px gap between the divs

please help.

Comment: It's the white-space. Add `line-height: 0` to `.content`.

Comment: @badcoder It's better to use `vertical-align: bottom;` for the images as: `.content img { vertical-align: bottom; }`. [reference](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18428997/center-image-element-in-parent-div/18429014#18429014).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's the white-space. Add `line-height: 0` to `.content`.

Answer (score 2):

You can also add `display: block` to `.content img`.

Comment: Thank you. This explains where the space is coming from, ie inline(-block) elements flowing and leaving space between lines. Adding line-height: 0 was voodoo for me personally.