# Placing images directly on top of each other

Tags: html, css, image

I have this HTML code, and I just want to place the images directly on top of each other. (so without this green line in between them)
How to do this?

Example URL: http://todolist.x10.mx/test.html

HTML Code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>

<html>
<head>

<title>test</title>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html">
</head>
<body bgcolor="green">
<img src="f.jpg" width="200" height="80" alt="plaatje1" style="border:none;padding:0px;spacing:0px;margin:0px"><br>
<img src="f.jpg" width="200" height="80" alt="plaatje2" style="border:none;padding:0px;spacing:0px;margin:0px"><br>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: you could use vertical-align =middle or margin bottom for the first image as -5px

Comment: Inline elements have no top/bottom margins.

Comment: @MohammedR.El-Khoudary `<img>` is an **replaced** inline element and top/bottom `margin` properties are applicable to images. [Verify that](http://jsbin.com/nobub/1/edit).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Don't use <br /> instead add the following CSS:

```
img {
margin: 0;
display: block;
}
```

Comment: It doesn't address the reason of the **green line** in between the images.

Comment: There're browser defaults .. have you tried setting margin: 0; padding: 0; in the * { } selector?

Comment: I'd help you better if you can provide me with a JSFiddle

Answer (score 1):

The **gap** belongs to the line height reserved character as the inline elements (the images in this case) are aligned vertically in their **baseline** by default.

You could align the inline elements vertically by [`vertical-align: middle;`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/vertical-align) (or `top`/`bottom`) to remove the vertical gap between the lines.

You can refer [my answer here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18428997/center-image-element-in-parent-div/18429014#18429014) for further info.

Also, you could simply remove the `<br>` between two lines and change the default display type of the images to `block`, as: `display: block;`.