# CSS Resize/Zoom-In effect on Image while keeping Dimensions

Tags: html, css, rollover

I would like to use the CSS3 `scale()` transition for a rollover effect, but I'd like to keep the rollover image dimensions the same.  So, the effect is that the image zooms in, but it remains constrained to its existing width and height.

```css
img:hover {
    transform:scale(1.5);
    -ms-transform:scale(1.5); /* IE 9 */
    -moz-transform:scale(1.5); /* Firefox */
    -webkit-transform:scale(1.5); /* Safari and Chrome */
    -o-transform:scale(1.5); /* Opera */
}
```

Here's a basic **[fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/9R2mx/)** to begin with.

But again, I want the image to keep the width/height.

I'm not married to using the css3 scale. Maybe there's a better way by resizing the element.

Comment: with DHTML use the "style" object and reset the transform propert e.g. document.getElementById("myimage").style.transform=" scale(1.8);";  the following two urls are what to see https://www.w3schools.com/howto/howto_css_zoom_hover.asp   https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/transition

Answer (score 77, accepted):

You could achieve that simply by wrapping the image by a `<div>` and adding [`overflow: hidden`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/overflow) to that element:

```
<div class="img-wrapper">
    <img src="..." />
</div>
```

```css
.img-wrapper {
    display: inline-block; /* change the default display type to inline-block */
    overflow: hidden;      /* hide the overflow */
}
```

**[WORKING DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/hashem/7vY7v/)**.

---

Also it's worth noting that `<img>` element (like the other inline elements) sits on its **[baseline](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Baseline_%28typography%29)** by default. And [there would be](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18428997/center-image-element-in-parent-div/18429014#18429014) a [`4~5px` gap at the bottom of the image](http://jsfiddle.net/hashem/7vY7v/6/).

That vertical gap belongs to the reserved space of descenders like: g j p q y. You could fix the alignment issue by adding [`vertical-align`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/vertical-align) property to the image with a value other than `baseline`.

Additionally for a better user experience, you could add [`transition`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/transition) to the images.

Thus we'll end up with the following:

```css
.img-wrapper img {
    transition: all .2s ease;
    vertical-align: middle;
}
```

**[UPDATED DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/hashem/7vY7v/4/)**.

```css
.img-wrapper {
    display: inline-block;
    overflow: hidden;
    
    border: 1px solid gray;
}

.img-wrapper img {
    -webkit-transition: all .2s ease;
    -moz-transition: all .2s ease;
    -ms-transition: all .2s ease;
    -o-transition: all .2s ease;
    transition: all .2s ease;
    
    vertical-align: middle;
}

.img-wrapper img:hover {
    -webkit-transform:scale(1.5); /* Safari and Chrome */
    -moz-transform:scale(1.5); /* Firefox */
    -ms-transform:scale(1.5); /* IE 9 */
    -o-transform:scale(1.5); /* Opera */
    transform:scale(1.5);
}
```

```html
<div class="img-wrapper">
    <img src="http://ts2.mm.bing.net/th?id=HN.608017620862175177&pid=15.1&H=160%20&W=80" />
</div>
```

Comment: Great idea.  I updated it a little to add a border to the wrapper, and set a height on the wrapper: http://jsfiddle.net/7vY7v/2/ (It was not wrapping the image tightly)

Comment: @mtyson What about adding `transition` to images? :) http://jsfiddle.net/hashem/7vY7v/3/

Comment: I was looking to do something like this that would be responsive but of course at some point you need to constrain a container that the image scales inside...ie a non percentage.